# Asking for a pay increase based on salary for similar positions

Tags: salary

In the past few weeks I've been contacted by recruiters for three different positions that pay about 15% more than I currently get, with seemingly similar benefits and all with short commutes.

Having had a very good year with the company where I've done the lion's share of the work on my team, I feel in a very good position to ask for raise.

I am very close to the edge of my payband so getting a sizeable pay increase is going to be tricky. Furthermore the bands are in flux at the moment due to, well reasons, but the short version is that they are unlikely to change in the next 6 to 12 months and currently there are boxes that I don't tick, even though these are no longer relevant

My question is, Would it be a good move to mention the positions at other companies when asking for a pay increase?

I'm just wondering if it could backfire in some way

Comment: No, don't mention them. Mention surveys instead.

Comment: If you ask for a rise and don't get it, what will you do? Ignore the 'payband' thing - they can always be broken for the right people. Ask for what you want, and if you don't get it, start talking to the recruiters.

Answer (score 3):

If you mention recruiters or other positions you're telling them you are looking for another job, which isn't good because it identifies you as a flight risk - forever. This will push you up the list if they need to make someone redundant.

Ask for a pay review, but I would only mention that you're doing the lion's share of the work, and based on industry standards you think x% would be a fair amount.

Comment: That's an interesting take. On average I get contacted by one recruiter a week, via mostly linkedIn, although to be fair sometimes i do get multiple recruiters contacting me about the same job ...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your boss is going to take it, can range from risk free to very risky. We don’t know what your supervisors temperament is so we can’t give you an assessment.

Instead of trying to predict what will happen on variables that are dependent on your boss, I’d suggest focusing on the ones important to YOU which I’m seeing as...

1. You like the job environment that you have
2. You like the 15% bump

With what you have on the table it’s either one or the other, so if you thrust your thinking 5 years in the future and realized that you’ve made a mistake, which mistake will be easier for you to live with...

a. I should’ve stayed, the environment was nicer even though the pay was lower

b. I should’ve left, the new environment would’ve sucked but I would’ve an additional x dollars under my name

c. I should’ve not listened to those recruiters

d. I should’ve not assumed that the environment would stay the same

e. Other regrets / mistakes

In the end, the answer will ultimately be yours to determine as different personalities handle the same set of facts differently.